# Killing processes on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, kill

I'm debugging plugins on Windows 7 and of course the plugin host (Cubase5.exe) occasionally crashes because of errors in the plugin. On XP or Vista, I could always restart it immediately and continue working. But on Windows 7, even though Cubase appears to close, it is still visible in Task Manager and I cannot kill it by any means. After a minute or two, it disappears by itself. In the mean time, I can't work because the plugin DLL is still locked by the process.

Does anyone know why this happens on Windows 7? I've already tried disabling Automatic Error Reporting but that didn't help. I've tried attaching cdb to Cubase, but I get:

```
Cannot debug pid 5252, NTSTATUS 0xC0000001
    "{Operation Failed}  The requested operation was unsuccessful."
Debuggee initialization failed, NTSTATUS 0xC0000001
    "{Operation Failed}  The requested operation was unsuccessful."
```

I tried following the instructions [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2005/08/17/unkillable-processes.aspx) but it appears this is only possible if I connect a second machine to my computer to debug it remotely.

Comment: Does Cubase close as expected when you don't load your addin? Or is there a safe mode so that no add-in is loaded?

Comment: My plugin causes Cubase to crash. The problem is that I can't quickly kill it afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the solution, using this article:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2005/08/17/unkillable-processes.aspx

This required installing the Windows Debugging Tools for Windows (nice name) and LiveKd, but by following the steps outlined I was able to track which driver was causing the process to hang: it turned out to be the 64-bit driver for the M-Audio Oxygen 8 V2 controller I'm using. Unfortunately no driver update is available.

Anyway, if anyone encounters a similar problem, this is the way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) by Mark Russinovich? It is really useful for "killing":)

Comment: Indeed it is, or the command line tool `pskill` from the same Sysinternals Suite.

Comment: Doesn't allow me to kill Cubase5 either. Inspection of the threads panel shows that there are two threads remaining, one of which seems to be in DllRegisterServer in ntdll.dll.

Comment: Do you have valid symbols for ntdll (use the MSFT public symbol server)?  It's almost certainly not in DllRegisterServer - that's probably just the closest public export.

Comment: i already use it. But seems the app is not killing some certain status like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have error reporting enabled, it's possible that werfault.exe has Cubase open to write a minidump for crash reporting purposes.

This is just a stab in the dark but it might be your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see werfault.exe in Task Manager though while I'm waiting for Cubase to close.

Comment: Bummer.  If you can't kill it with taskmgr or pskill, it's probably blocked waiting on a kernel thread somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's most likely a driver that won't cancel, as explained in the link I gave in the question. But attaching a kernel debugger is a bit too much for me...

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to check with **Process Monitor** what Cubase is doing. Set a filter so that everything with a process name containing "cubase" will be recorded. It could be that you are facing some timeout issue when Cubase wants to exit.

Answer (score 0):

you can end the process the service is running under. You can find this process by going to the Services tab of the Task Manager, right-clicking, and selecting Go To Process(**you need to click the Show processes from all users button.**). Note that one process may host multiple services (especially if it's svchost.exe), and ending the process will kill all those services. Also, this is an unclean exit, and may cause data corruption depending on what the service(s) was doing when you killed it.

Depending on which specific service you are trying to stop, there may be a cleaner way to simulate failure.